# My .htaccess is still not read despite AllowOverride All (Apache2 / Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp, .htaccess

I've installed Lamp server on my system, it's set up to work on an other directory than var/www/html, my localhost it's link to a folder named Sites (home/quentin/Sites). After the installation all seems to work well. But I'm programming website with the Kirby CMS, and I've some 404 errors (like my server cannot get images). For the technical support (of kirby) it's look like my .htaccess file isn't read by apache2 (I add some random character on my .htaccess, and there is no error message after his modification).

I've created a specific configuration file in the folder sites-available of apache2, named sites.conf where I set `AllowOverride All`, you can see what I have write in this file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/quentin/Sites
<Directory "/home/quentin/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.public.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.public.log combined
```

I've modified also the apache2.conf and set in each `<directory>` the `AllowOverride All` property.
Here you can see all the directories set in this file :

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/quentin/Sites>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've also verified if my `AccessFileName .htacces` was uncommented.

After hour of searching, I still have my error...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `ServerName` directive in your vHost? No HTTPS? "in the folder sites-available" - Shouldn't this be in `sites-enabled`? Or create a symlink back to `sites-available`? _Aside:_ You should not set this in the `<Directory />` container - this should be `AllowOverride None` and `Require all denied`.

Comment: "404 errors (like my server cannot get images)" - I've not used Kirby CMS, but images (and other static resources) don't normally go through the CMS (unless you are protecting them behind some authorisation)? So, `.htaccess` would not notmally have anything to do with serving "images"?

Comment: The .htaccess is here to get the direction of the images and for rewrite the url the images. After multiple inspection, it's still look like my .htaccess isn't taken into consideration